# Querying WordPress WP-API for lots of posts (using promises!)

Tags: node.js, wordpress, promise, axios, wp-api

**I am working on a Node.js application which uses the WordPress JSON API as a kind of headless CMS.** When the application spins up, we query out to the WP database and pull in the information we need *(using Axios)*, manipulate it, and store it temporarily.

Simple enough - but one of our post categories in the CMS has a rather large number of entries. For some godforsaken reason, WordPress has capped the API request limit to a maximum of 99 posts at a time, and requires that we *write a loop that can send concurrent API requests until all the data has been pulled.*

For instance, if we have 250 posts of some given type, I need to hit that route three separate times, specifying the specific "page" of data I want each time.

Per the docs, https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/, I have access to a `?page=` query string that I can use to send these requests concurrently. *(i.e. `...&page=2`*)

I also have access to `X-WP-Total` in the headers object, which gives me the total number of posts within the given category.

However, these API calls are part of a nested promise chain, and the whole process **needs to return a promise I can continue chaining off of.**

The idea is to make it dynamic so it will always pull all of the data, and return it as one giant array of posts. Here's what I have, which **is functional:**

```
const request = require('axios');

module.exports = (request_url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  // START WITH SMALL ARBITRARY REQUEST TO GET TOTAL NUMBER OF POSTS FAST
  request.get(request_url + '&per_page=1').then(
    (apiData) => {

      // SETUP FOR PROMISE.ALL()
      let promiseArray = [];

      // COMPUTE HOW MANY REQUESTS WE NEED
      // ALWAYS ROUND TOTAL NUMBER OF PAGES UP TO GET ALL THE DATA
      const totalPages = Math.ceil(apiData.headers['x-wp-total']/99);

      for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        promiseArray.push( request.get(`${request_url}&per_page=99&page=${i}`) )
      };

      resolve(
        Promise.all(promiseArray)
               .then((resolvedArray) => {

                 // PUSH IT ALL INTO A SINGLE ARRAY
                 let compiledPosts = [];

                 resolvedArray.forEach((axios_response) => {
                   // AXIOS MAKES US ACCESS W/RES.DATA
                   axios_response.data.forEach((post) => {
                     compiledPosts.push(post);
                   })
                 });

                 // RETURN AN ARRAY OF ALL POSTS REGARDLESS OF LENGTH
                 return compiledPosts;
               }).catch((e) => { console.log('ERROR'); reject(e);})
       )
    }
  ).catch((e) => { console.log('ERROR'); reject(e);})
})
```

Any creative ideas to make this pattern better?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same question. In my case, I use Vue Resource :

```
this.$resource('wp/v2/media').query().then((response) => {   

  let pagesNumber = Math.ceil(response.headers.get('X-WP-TotalPages'));

  for(let i=1; i <= pagesNumber; i++) {
       this.$resource('wp/v2/media?page='+ i).query().then((response) => {
           this.medias.push(response.data);
           this.medias = _.flatten(this.medias);
           console.log(this.medias);
       });
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is a better workaround to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there should be. WP used to let you modify a file (wp-settings I think) to turn off the batch limit, but has now apparently baked it into core. Best solution we have found is to store a shallow copy of the data we need locally, and check periodically for updates. Not an Ideal solution and we won't be using WP-API in the future, probably.